# Elementary OS error with rc local orig No such file or directory

Tags: linux, boot, parallels, elementaryos

rc.local shows

```
rm-fR /var/lib/apt/lists/*
mv /etc/rc.local.orig /etc/rc.local
exit 0
```

When ever I try to boot the system I get

```
mv: cannot stat '/etc/rc.local.orig': No such file or directory
```

Don't really understand what the error is and didn't want to try to just comment out the second line in rc.local. Should I create the file rc.local.orig and is that a copy of rc.local?

One thing to note is that I am running this on parallels vm